# Java EE 6 Eclipse JAX-RS deployment issue

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, glassfish-3

I am following a tutorial that shows how to setup JAX-RS. However, I am getting an error when I reach a certain part in the tutorial.

The tutorial is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on557289GzA&feature=related

At one stage it says to perform the following:

> Click Properties
>   -> Click Project Facets
>   -> Click JAX-RS(REST Web Service)
>   -> Click further configuration
>   -> Click OK

I then click apply, in the tutorial this should then generate the relevant files, however in my implementation I get the following error:

> cannot Deploy HelloWorld Deployment
>   Error for module: HelloWorld:
>   Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
>   The ResourceConfig instance does not
>   contain any root resource
>   classes.%%%EOL%%%

I am using a "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6)" and "Java 1.6.0.22".

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: GlassFish should already contain JAX-RS as part of Java EE 6.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your `web.xml` file (mine was when I had a similar error), make sure that your servlet is setup looking like this:

```
<servlet>  
    <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>  
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>  
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer  
    </servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
```

If this does not help, please comment with further information on what the issue is (are the jar files being imported correctly for JAX-RS, or if it is a configuration issue)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and it was solved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093134/686036) from a similar question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412147/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes) (The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes)