# Mapping URL to Java methods using Google App Engine and Jersey

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, restlet

I am trying to run the [HelloWorld example for Jersey](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggnxo/index.html), but failing. This is what I've tried.

I have setup my `appengine-web.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>server</application>
  <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I have setup my `web.xml` like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>server</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>server</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have my service setup like this,

```
package com;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class service {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    private String getString(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I am using these libs

`asm-3.3.1.jar`
`jersey-bundle-1.12.jar`
`jersey-core-1.12.jar`
`jersey-server-1.12.jar`

Here's a video of the issue http://screencast.com/t/oIYKMQw1x

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Stack trace

> Apr 23, 2012 12:19:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules 
>   SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource
>   classes. Apr 23, 2012 12:19:27 AM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log SEVERE:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig
>   instance does not contain any root resource classes.  at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1308)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:773)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:773)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:768)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:607)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:208)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:189)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:128)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:104)

Comment: I've been there - Restlet is too complicated and opaque. I recommend using RESTeasy or Jersey. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey

Comment: @PeterKnego Still no luck. I've add a lot more information about the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412147/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that I was mapping to `com.service` which is the class. I needed to map to the package containing my class.