# RESTful services HTTP Status 500 Servlet.init() error

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets

Here's my code for java class named as Person.java:

```
package forage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person() {

        id = -1;
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        email = "";

    }

    public Person(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }


    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

}
```

Here's the code for resources that i created Personresources.java:

```
 package forageresource;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;

import forage.Person;

@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {

    private final static String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    private final static String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    private final static String EMAIL = "email";

    private Person person = new Person(1, "Sample", "Person", "sample_person@jerseyrest.com");

    // The @Context annotation allows us to have certain contextual objects
    // injected into this class.
    // UriInfo object allows us to get URI information (no kidding).
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    // Another "injected" object. This allows us to use the information that's
    // part of any incoming request.
    // We could, for example, get header information, or the requestor's address.
    @Context
    Request request;

    // Basic "is the service running" test
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String respondAsReady() {
        return "Demo service is ready!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("sample")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getSamplePerson() {

        System.out.println("Returning sample person: " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName());

        return person;
    }

    // Use data from the client source to create a new Person object, returned in JSON format.  
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person postPerson(
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> personParams
            ) {

        String firstName = personParams.getFirst(FIRST_NAME);
        String lastName = personParams.getFirst(LAST_NAME);
        String email = personParams.getFirst(EMAIL);

        System.out.println("Storing posted " + firstName + " " + lastName + "  " + email);

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setEmail(email);

        System.out.println("person info: " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + " " + person.getEmail());

        return person;

    }
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>JerseyRESTServer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Person</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally the error:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
```

I am new with REST services i don't know what is going wrong. Please guide me
I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0, Eclipse mars and i am referring from this site:
http://avilyne.com/?p=105

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412147/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Look at the highest voted answer.

Comment: But it is already there!! The <param-name> you are talking about

Comment: Is `Person` a package? I don't think so

Comment: No its a class a POJO class in forage package.

Comment: You need to put the name of the package the rsource class is in

Comment: <!--   <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Person</param-value>
    </init-param> -->
    <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>forage</param-value>
</init-param>
    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: That is NOT the name of the package the RESOURCE CLASS is in. That is the package of the POJO

Comment: @peeskillet Thank you so so much for being so patient with me! I really appreciate for help!