# Container Exception while starting tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I am getting the following error while trying to start the tomcat server.

The same code is running on different machine. I removed and again added the jdk in eclipse, deleted the project again imported it and also changed the workspace, it is still not working.

```
    com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412147/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes)

Comment: tried it not working, POM is having all dependencies in it. the code is working on one machine but not in other

Comment: can you add the step how you imported the project?