# Unable to setup a hello world Jersey application

Tags: java, rest, jersey

**Background**

I need to make some customisation in Jersey logging in my project. As was unable to find any clue how to do it - [Unable to customize Jersey LoggingFilter to hide user token, getting - PMD violation during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277082/unable-to-customize-jersey-loggingfilter-to-hide-user-token-getting-pmd-viola), I looked for setting up a hello-world application first. I followed this article - https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jax-rs-jersey-hello-world-example/, even though it seems to use Jersey 1.17.1 - pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
  <artifactId>JerseyHelloWorld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JerseyHelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>JerseyHelloWorld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.jersey.logging</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest-points/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Entry point -

```
package com.jersey.logging;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/show-on-screen")
public class JerseyHelloWorldService
{
    @GET
    @Path("/{message}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("message") String msg)
    {
        String output = "Message requested : " + msg;
        //Simply return the parameter passed as message
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

But when I do this setup, I get the following error on trying to run this application -

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4883)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I get the following exception on browsing to http://localhost:8080/jersey-logging-demo/rest-points/show-on-screen/something -

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 09, 2020 5:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [jersey-serlvet]
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Even if I download the source from there - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7yo2HclmjI4QWtrUmRlNzVxa2s/edit?usp=sharing, I get a 404 error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412147/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes

Comment: I followed the steps shown there. I have shown all my files here. I don't know why but this demo worked for me https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/. I compared all the files - pom, web.xml and service. I even overwrote my project with the files from the working one but still.